# What is the point of state pensions topup

Tags: united-kingdom, pension

The UK Government are offering a pension topup scheme details here:

https://www.gov.uk/state-pension-topup

Going on the above example, it would take 20 years to recover your initial 4k outlay compared to just putting that money in the bank with a 1% savings rate (which you can easily exceed if you're savvy).

By that point the guy is now 88.  Even if he lives another 5 years he's still only £1400 quid up.  And thats an ENORMOUS IF.

PLUS what on earth will he do with an extra 260 quid a year when he's 88. Nothing useful. It wont cover the no doubt enormous costs of care, so it just doesn't make any sense to me whatsoever.

There is one option - perhaps he hates his children and wants to ensure they don't get as much inheritance?

Perhaps there is a use case, some combination of age/gender etc, personal circumstances, where this does make sense?

(The government does already separately offer schemes for women who dont have enough NICs to top up their pension - so it's can't be that example)

Answer (score 3):

This scheme is specifically aimed at giving a bit extra to people who have reached or will reach pension age before April 2016 when the new flat-rate pension comes in.  The new scheme will pay somewhat more than the current one, so this scheme is intended to provide some compensation.

A couple of points which aren't mentioned on the calculator but are in [various](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/finance/personalfinance/pensions/10756794/Should-you-buy-extra-25-a-week-in-state-pension.html) [articles](http://www.thisismoney.co.uk/money/pensions/article-3202732/How-new-state-pension-TREBLE-income-Women-self-employed-set-benefit-DWP-scheme.html):

- The top-up payment is index linked; it will rise in line with inflation. UK inflation is currently very low but that could change.
- The top-up payment could outlive you; if you're married 50% of the top-up payment will go to your spouse if you die first.

It's a much better deal than you could get buying an annuity on the open market at the moment but it does have the same major downsides as any annuity:

- loss of flexibility since you give up the capital
- value is dependent on how long you (and/or your spouse) live.  You might be quids in but you might also lose big.

It's not a no-brainer but nor is it an obviously bad deal.

Comment: OK Interesting.  The index linking means he's in profit 2 years earlier. Still not a biggie.  As for 50% going to spouse.. well meh. You've still lost it.  I Don't really understand how it's compensation if they're expected to stump up a massive downpayment.

Comment: @Codek Think of it as longevity insurance; you won't outlive life annuity income, but can outlive your savings.

Comment: @codek It's compensation in the sense that it's effectively a government-subsidised annuity.  It'd cost much more to buy something equivalent privately.

*If* you fancy trading capital for guaranteed income it's the cheapest game in town by a good way.